# Google Play Store Suspension Whereabouts [edited]

Tags: android, google-play

**Edit**

Due to the certain number of complaints from the people I cooperate with, I would like to reopen this issue due to the new Google Content Policy strategies in mind. Google, unlike Apple, is very stingy with the real explanation why your application is suspended. I'm an iOS developer too and I have experience with App Store rejections, but backed up with screenshots and actual explanations (I was even amazed how did they manage to find those well hidden news and take actual screenshots. Yes, it was a news app).

Recently, I reworked and updated an old "hybrid" app to be fully native one. I've changed nothing related to the content, but only to make it a fully native one. That app got rejected for not complying to the "Gambling Content Policy", after 2 months.

This is a new problem and I would like if we could share problems, solutions here. Advices can come in handy, too.

[You can read this too. Same situation with different content.](http://andrewpearson.org/?p=681)

**[remove these edits if this is NOT covered elsewhere]**

**Original**

Been looking for a guide to app suspension from Google play and been struggling to find one so, based on trawling Stack Overflow and the official Android developer forum have put together a guide for what occurs when an app is suspended from the Google Play (Android marketplace).

There are some questions interspersed, so if you have first-hand experience of this would be good to hear from you, thanks.

May be worth bearing in mind that Google's Play store [TOS](https://play.google.com/intl/en_uk/about/play-terms.html) is updated from time to time and that if your app is currently compliant that may change, at the whim of Google, at some point in future.

- If your app is suspended from the Google Play you will receive a notification email from Google to the developer email associated with your publisher account. Google will list the applicable TOS rules that your app is in breach of. They don’t usually go into too much detail.
- You can reply to the notification email and appeal the decision. Having proof to back up your claims will certainly help, for example if your app was suspended due to copyright infringement, being able to prove you have an agreement with the rights holder should be sufficient to ensure your app is reinstated.
- Based on your appeal Google may un-suspend your app. This usually happens within a day or two. If your app is un-suspended you’ll have the option to republish it via your Google Play publisher account, under the same package. Existing users will be able to keep their existing settings and in-app purchases.
  Do in-app purchases need to be restored?
- Google may choose not to reply to your appeal. In which case your app may remain suspended. Suspended apps are no longer live in the Google Play store and their package is no longer available to publish to. What does having a suspended app mean to the end user? Are they blocked from opening the app, or just not able to access it’s page on the Google play store and they will no longer receive updates? What options are open to users that have made in-app purchases on suspended apps?
- If your appeal was unsuccessful you can choose to try to fix this issues Google outlined and republish your app under a different package but you’ll of course be starting from scratch with no users and no way to transfer in-app purchases, unless you maintained a separate database of purchases. Not sure on the last point.
- Google can choose to close publisher accounts that are repeat offenders. When a publisher account is closed by Google all apps associated with that account are also suspended.